# having trouble compiling old VC++ 6 c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to compile MSVC 6 C++ code using MSVC 2008 Express on 64 bit windows 7. When I tried to open the `.sln` file, I get the error "project file `dpcwebcfx.vproj` could not be loaded". I don't have the `.vproj` file, but I do have `dpcwebcfx.dsw` file. So in the `.sln` file I changed

```
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "dpcwebcfx", "dpcwebcfx.vcproj", "{355F3EB4-3B37-4272-B454-340E9B3BD9D3}"
```

to

```
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "dpcwebcfx", "dpcwebcfx.dsw", "{355F3EB4-3B37-4272-B454-340E9B3BD9D3}"
```

Now I get an error converting the dsw file: Cannot load the project due to a corrupt project file. What should I do? Am I missing a file so that I can't open this project?

Comment: Need more information than that. What error are you getting on the conversion?

Comment: You could always create a new solution and add the code to it.

Comment: Also, aren't dsw files the solution files for Visual C++ 6.0? You should open *that* In Visual C++ 2008. The project files are dsp, IIRC. Or you could just do as Derek suggests :)

Comment: Try to recompile your VC++ 6.0 project in VC++ 2008 using function *File->New->Project From Existing Code*.

Comment: hey SChepurin, I was able to the successfully build my project and generate a dll file by opening the file using new Project from existing code. However, the new dll vc generated is only 106 kb when the older 32 bit ddl file generated from the same source code is 1.78 mb. I am using the dll for my coldfusion custom tag and coldfusion still give unable to load library null error. Do you know what can cause this